# How ro get and install KB with state 'Pending install'

Tags: powershell

I faced to an issue and need your remarks and recommendations about Windows Update with powershell.
Basically i use module PSWindowsUpdate which works well and automate WU by script.[image]

My situation is the following (see screenshot):

- From User interface, we see that an update is on *pending install*
- However command Get-WUList indicates that there is no KB candidate (whatever the state)

How can retrieve the KB with state 'Pendint install' and of course install them with powershell ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code will show Pending updates:

```
Clear-Host
   $TStr = ""
   $fmtUpds =
    @{Expression={&{
    Switch ($_.MsrcSeverity) {
          1 {"Critical"}
          2 {"Important"}
          3 {"Moderate"}
          4 {"Low"}
          5 {"Unspecified"}
          Default {"Other"}
    }}};Label="`nSeverity";Width=9},
    @{Expression={"{0:N1} MB" -f ($_.Size / 1MB)};
                  Label="`n    Size";
                  Width=8; Align="Right"},
    @{Expression={$_.BrowseOnly};Label="Browse`nOnly";
                  Width=6; Align="Left"},
    @{Expression={$_.IsDownLoaded};Label="Down`nloaded";
                  Width=6; Align="Left"},
    @{Expression={$_.RebootRequired};Label="Reboot`nReq.";
                  Width=6; Align="Left"},
    @{Expression={$_.Title};Label="`nDescription";Align="Left"}

  Try {
       $PU = get-windowsUpdate -ErrorAction Stop   |
             Where-Object {$_.IsHidden -eq $False} |
             Format-Table -Property $fmtUpds -Wrap |
             Out-String

       If ($PU -eq "") { $PU = "`tNo Pending Updates Found!" |
         Out-String}
  }
  Catch {$PU = "`n`tRequires Administrative privledges to report"}

  Try {
       $HU = get-windowsUpdate -ErrorAction Stop   |
             Where-Object {$_.IsHidden -eq $True}  |
             Format-Table -Property $fmtUpds -Wrap |
             Out-String

       If ($HU -eq "") { $HU = "`tNo Hidden Updates Found!`n" |
         Out-String}
  }
  Catch {$HU =
           "`n`tRequires Administrative privileges to report`n"}

  $TStr += ("`nPending Updates:" | Out-String) +
             ($PU | Out-String) +
           ("`nHidden Updates: " | Out-String) +
             ($HU | Out-String)

$TStr
```

Sample Output:

```
Pending Updates:

                   Browse Down   Reboot                                        
Severity      Size Only   loaded Req.   Description                            
--------- -------- ------ ------ ------ ------------                           
Other       5.0 MB False  False  False  Dell. - Firmware - 0.1.0.23            
Other       0.5 MB False  False  False  Intel - SoftwareComponent -            
                                        1.41.2021.121                          
Other      16.0 MB False  False  False  Intel - SoftwareComponent - 1.63.1155.1
Other      47.0 MB False  False  False  Intel - SoftwareComponent - 2130.1.16.1
Other       5.0 MB False  False  False  SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd.  - Modem 
                                        - 2.19.1.0                             
Other       5.0 MB False  False  False  SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd.  - USB - 
                                        2.19.1.0                               

Hidden Updates: 
    No Hidden Updates Found!

PS>
```

Comment: Hi retiredGeek. Thanks for your script and time you spent to help me. Unfortunately your script does not list the KB i provided in my screenshot (remind in my screenshot it is an update already downloaded and ready to be install/pending install). However your script works well to detect an update that needs to be downloaded.